# Basis of $\mathbb{Q}(t)$ over $\mathbb{Q}(t^3-2)$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

While solving some problems in galois theory. I got to know that $\mathbb{Q}(t)$ over $\mathbb{Q}(t^3-2)$ is a finite extension.
But I am not sure how do I get a basis explicitly.
Can anyone help me with this. I know the minimal polynomial but still I would like to get a basis explicitly.

Further I have following question.

Can I write $\mathbb{Q}(t) \equiv \mathbb{Q}(t^3-2)/(f(t)$ for some polynomial $f(t)$?

I can see that
$\mathbb{Q}(t) =\mathbb{Q}(t^3-2)(t) \equiv \frac{\mathbb{Q}(t^3-2)[x]}{(x^3-2-(t^3-2))}$

so can I say that $\{1,t,t^2\}$ is a basis but I would like to see how any element is being spanned by these **explicitly**. I know linear independence is difficult to prove because that basically means that the polynomial is irreducible.

Comment: Note that $\mathbb{Q}(t^3-2)=\mathbb{Q}(t^3)$

Comment: @lhf, then consider a polynomial $t^3-2t^2+t$ Instead of $t^3-2$. What matters is a method not the polynomial.

Comment: It is best to put $u=t^3-2$ and then $\mathbb{Q} (t) $ is of degree $3$ over $\mathbb{Q}(u)$. Key step here is to prove that the polynomial $x^3-u-2\in\mathbb{Q}(u)[x]$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q} (u) $ and then we get $\{1,t,t^2\} $ as desired basis.

Comment: Many books typically include the proof as a part of a standard theorem that if $u$ is a rational function of $t$ i.e. $u\in F(t) $ then $F(t) $ is a finite extension of $F(u) $. Check if this is handled in your textbook.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh, yes it is there however I am looking for some additional information.

Answer (score 2):

First note that any polynomial in $ P\in\mathbb{Q}[t]$ can be written uniquely in the form $P=A+Bt+Ct^2$ where $A,B,C\in\mathbb{Q}[t^3-2]$. Then the equation of the form $PQ=1$ in $\mathbb{Q}(t)=\mathbb{Q}(t^3-2)[x]/(x^3-2-(t^3-2))$ can be solved in the form $Q=A'+B't+C't^2$, now $A',B',C'\in\mathbb{Q}(t^3-2)$. The reason is that by using the relation $x^3-2=t^3-2$ we can reduce the left hand side of the equation to degree $\le2$, and we can compare the coefficients, which amounts to solving 3 linear equations in $\mathbb{Q}(t^3-2)$. The solution must exist, sice if not, the ideal $  (P)\in\mathbb{Q}(t^3-2)[x]/(x^3-2-(t^3-2))$ do not contain 1, whic occurs only when $P=0$. And we have obtained every element $\frac{P}{Q}\in \mathbb{Q}(t)$ in the desired form.

Let us work on the exapmle $$ \frac{P}{Q}=\frac{t^4-2t}{t^4+1}.$$
Let us denote $T=t^3-2$. First, we want to represent $P$ and $Q^{-1}$ as polynomials of degree $\le 2$ in $\mathbb{Q}(T)$. We can write
$$\begin{cases} P=Tt \\ 
Q=(T+2)t+1 \end{cases}.$$
Next, using the relation $t^3=T+2$, $$(at^2+bt+c)Q=(a+b(T+2))t^2+(b+c(T+2))t+a(T+2)^2+c=1$$
and we can compare the coefficients. We obtain $$Q^{-1}=\frac{(T+2)^2}{(T+2)^4+1}t^2-\frac{T+2}{(T+2)^4+1}t+\frac{1}{(T+2)^4+1}.$$
Multiplying $P$ and $Q^{-1}$, and again using $t^3=T+2$,$$\frac{P}{Q}=-\frac{T(T+2)}{(T+2)^4+1}t^2+\frac{T}{(T+2)^4+1}t+\frac{T(T+2)^3}{(T+2)^4+1}.$$

Comment: couldn't understand how you are dealing with the denominator

Comment: I added an exapmle. As you can see, this involves a fair amount of computation.